# Jupyter Notebook Plotly Plots Working In Firefox But Not Chrome (R)

Tags: r, google-chrome, firefox, jupyter-notebook, google-analytics

I'm new to using notebooks, and I'm just wondering why my Jupyter notebook plots are showing up on Firefox, but they are blank when i use Chrome.

Comment: Have you checked your Chrome browser console to see if there is any error? Right-click on the page, go to "Inspect" then go to "Console". Also, it could be that Jupyter is not compatible with Chrome. If Chrome is your default system browser, here is how to change it for Jupyter on a Windows machine https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows/